# Using the Facebook JavaScript SDK

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

This is going to be as beginner a question with getting started as you're like to encounter.

I've done previous programming with Facebook but not directly as web programming - so, I know my way around the Graph API and how things work in general, but I don't have any experience doing web programming and I'm a little lost on how to get from [Facebook's](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/) [documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/getting-started/) to having a working web page that lets me log in (the goal is to just have as plain of HTML/JavaScript as possible, but allowing uploading of images and posting links and such on walls using the publish_stream permission).

Here's the code I have so far from going through what Facebook has told me to do (and the small amount I added on from having seen a small amount of HTML before now):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
<head>
    The title of the document (test text)
</head>
<body>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
// init the Facebook JavaScript SDK
    FB.init({
        appId       : 'EDITED OUT FOR PRIVACY BUT IS VALID IN MY CODE',
        channelUrl  : null,
        status      : true,
        cookie      : false,
        xfbml       : false
    });

    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
        if (response.status === 'connected') {
            // connected
        } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
            // not authorized
            login();
        } else {
            // not_logged_in
            login();
        }
    });
};

function login() {
    FB.login(function(response) {
        if (response.authResponse) {
            // connected
            testAPI();
        } else {
            // cancelled
        }
    });
}

function testAPI() {
    console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information... ');
    FB.api('/me', function(response) {
        console.log('Good to see you, ' + response.name + '.');
    });
}

(function(d){
    var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
    js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
    ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
}(document));
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

When I save this as a .html file and drop it into Firefox, nothing is displayed (unless I type in some hello world text before `</body>`). I've looked into JavaScript / HTML tutorials on how to get things running, but to no avail.

I know that it says in the Prerequisites section of a previous link (I'd link it again but I'm too new here and stackoverflow won't let me) that "You'll need somewhere that let's you host HTML files online." It also references Heroku, but any resource I can find on that takes me to app-hosting, and I don't get why (this is just to test this functionality) I would need to host it online in the first place instead of just dropping it into my browser (or call `ShellExecute` from C/C++ to get it to run).

[EDIT:] Thanks for all your help so far everyone, I just wish I hadn't taken up time with typos so far instead of allowing all you helpful people to get to the root of the problem.

Comment: Is this the exact code you copied? It seems you're missing the closing brace `}` for the testAPI() function.

Comment: Thanks! Edited and fixed. But I still have the same problem. Blank page still.

Comment: First of all, check your popup blocker settings – since you are calling FB.login (which used this way tries to open a popup) without any user interaction, it’s likely to get blocked by most browser’s default blocker configuration. FB.login opening a popup should under general circumstances only be used on explicit user interaction, f.e clicking on some button. Btw., that’s right on top of the docs page.

Comment: I forgot to mention I had disabled the pop-up blocker for this (just to get some basic functionality to make sure the basics work). With the blocker disabled, I still get a blank page that does nothing (or doesn't seem to do anything).

Comment: BTW, you don't close `head`, neither `html` tag.

Comment: Thanks. Fixed and edited above. As you can see, I'm pretty new to HTML, please forgive my silly mistakes. Still have the same issues, though. Looking into a new resource I just found, but I'm still having the same problem (the page isn't completely blank now that I added in "The title of the document (test text)" in the `head` area).

Comment: Looks like there are a couple more typos - the FB.Init should be FB.init, and the javascript source line should be js.src, not js src

Comment: I was just about to edit it with the js.src fix (thanks to just having found Ctrl+Shift+K in Firefox), but the FB.Init->FB.init problem definitely would've taken me a while longer. Thanks! Edited again, but once again, still the same problem - and, according to the Ctrl+Shift+K window (Web Console), logging has been disabled by a script, so it's still pretty hard to debug.

**Page still nonfunctional

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The reason the page is blank is because, no display HTML was intended to be shown. The point of the example was to demonstrate the login and API calls.

If you logged in already, then you will not see anything as indicated at

```
FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
        if (response.status === 'connected') {
            // connected
                        // <----- no calls
        } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
            // not authorized
            login();
        } else {
            // not_logged_in
            login();
        }
    });
};
```

So if you want to know if it is working when you have logged in already, try placing testAPI() here

```
if (response.status === 'connected') {
    // connected
    testAPI(); // <---------------
} else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
```

Comment: @phwd  for connected user how can we fetch publish permission ?